# Does SwiftUI's ForEach cache @State variables of child views beyond their existence?

Tags: swiftui

So here is a little piece of code that sums up a problem I cannot figure out atm.

In the code below I add and remove entries to a dictionary keyed by an Enum.

What I would expect is that every time I add an item a new random number is being generated in the Element view and displayed.

What happens is that for every same Ident the same random number shows up - event though the ForEach loop has had a state where that Ident key was not in the dictionary any more. It appears as if ForEach does not purge the @State vars of the Element views that are not present any more, but reuses them when a new entry to the dictionary is added with the same Ident.

Is this expected behavior? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


enum Ident:Int, Comparable, CaseIterable {
    case one=1, two, three, four
    
    static func < (lhs: Ident, rhs: Ident) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
    
}

extension Dictionary where Key == Ident,Value== String {
    
    var asSortedArray:Array<(Ident,Value)> {
        Array(self).sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
    }
    
    var nextKey:Ident? {
        if self.isEmpty {
            return .one
        }
        else {
            return Array(Set(Ident.allCases).subtracting(Set(self.keys))).sorted().first
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dictionary:[Ident:String] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                ForEach(dictionary.asSortedArray, id: \.0) { (ident, text) in
                    Element(dictionary: $dictionary, ident: ident, text: text)
                }
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    if let nextIdent = dictionary.nextKey {
                        dictionary[nextIdent] = "Something"
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add one")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Element:View {
    @Binding var dictionary:[Ident:String]
    var ident:Ident
    var text:String
    @State var random:Int = Int.random(in: 0...1000)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(ident.rawValue))
            Text(String(random))
            Button(action: {
                dictionary.removeValue(forKey: ident)
            }, label: {
                Text("Delete me.")
            })
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment, every time you add a new element, the whole ForEach is redrawn. That is a bad practice. Use an array of Identifiable struct instead of the dictionary.

Comment: @mahan If you look closely at my code the dictionary is turned into an Array of  tuples, with the first value being the key (Ident) which also serves as Identity for the child view. All good here I believe, that does not cause the problem with the state variables. In contrary when I use some randomly generated UUID as identity and force everything to redraw every time, the state variables get updated properly.